# Android - GridView with a custom adapter doesn't work

Tags: java, android, gridview, custom-adapter

I've created a Custom Adapter for ListView and GridView. It's all the same, I just want one tab with List, other with GridView. I can set the data to ListView on Fragment1 but I can not do the same for GridView on Fragment2 (Gives a Null Pointer Exception).

Codes are below :

**Fragment2.java :**

```
public class FragmentTab2 extends Fragment {
    GridView gridView;
    Intent intent;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab2, container, false);
        gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.GridView1);
        return rootView;
    }
    public GridView getGridView() {
        return gridView;
    }
}
```

**CustomAdapter.java :**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<ListData> data;
    private Context context;

    CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListData> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View rowView = convertView;

        if(rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        ImageView image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.listLogo);
        TextView nameVideo = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        TextView link = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.link);

        // Get individual object from  ArrayList<ListData> and set ListView items
        ListData temp_data = data.get(position);
        image.setImageBitmap(temp_data.getImage());
        nameVideo.setText(temp_data.getName());
        link.setText(temp_data.getLink());

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

**And the main**

```
ListView lw = fragmentTab1.getListView();
        lw.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, dataArray));
        GridView gr = fragmentTab2.getGridView();
        //gr.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, dataArray));
```

The commented part is giving the Null Exception, everything else is fine. Any ideas?
Thanks.

```
android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentTab2);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
```

Comment: Could you please provide full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `fragmentTab2.getGridView();` is returning null.

Make sure the GridView in your `fragmenttab2` actually has the id `GridView1`.

Comment: It does, Look :  gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.GridView1); and than I'm calling it to the Activity with a simple get method.

Comment: I mean in your `fragmenttab2.xml` file.

Comment: There, aswell : android:id="@+id/GridView1"

Comment: Ok - Also if your `fragmentTab2` isn't created yet (the `onCreateView(..)` didn't run) then your `fragmentTab2.getGridView()` will return null.

Comment: I see, how can I run it other than doing (Editid it to my question's last element)

Comment: I'd have to see more of your code to get a better understanding of exactly what you're doing but since it's working with a ListView I'd say follow the same steps you're using to acquire a non-null ListView from your fragment1.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with the dataArray may be its consumed for first adapter try to set separate array in grid and check